# Finding the list of any Lint rule of any category

Tags: android, lint

I've recently started to use Lint with Gradle and I've generated my first report.

The report displays those warnings and errors found in my app, grouped by their respective categories (Usability, Correctness, ecc...)

For each category, the report is only showing the warnings and errors (the "rules") found in the app, but I would like to know the name of any rule of any group, as by means of ListOptions I would like to configure specific warnings as errors, even if I don't know what's the name of their "rule".

Is there an option available with LintOptions to see any of them or a specific Android reference of the complete list of "rules"?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android Studio go to `Code -> Inspect Code` and click on the ellipsis next to  `Inspection Profile`. That brings up a panel with all the Lint inspections, and you can edit their severity from there.

[image: inspection profile]

[image: lint contents]

EDIT:

> For a full list of lint-supported issues and their corresponding
> issue IDs,
>
> run the `lint --list` command.

[source](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint#pref)

Comment: Hi, thanks. I've already known this section, but what I would know is their rule "id", which is different from their "Description"

Comment: @AlessandroViolante if you click on each of those you will also see the name of the Issue ID being displayed on the right. Not sure about a full list though

Comment: @AlessandroViolante I think I found the answer you were looking for in the docs. Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is web version of the official Android Lint rules (by severity):
https://googlesamples.github.io/android-custom-lint-rules/checks/severity.md.html